# Laravel Validating An Array in Update Method With Multiple Rows Needing Ignoring

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to validate an array within the update method which means I need to ignore the `id`'s of the rows so that it doesn'r return the error:

> contactName has already been taken

Here is my validation from my update method of my controller:

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $brand = Brand::findOrFail($id);

    $request->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', Rule::unique('brands')->ignore($id)],
        'contactNames' => ['required', 'array'],
        'contactNames.*' => ['required', 'max:255', 'string', 'distinct', Rule::unique('brand_managers', 'name')->ignore( //what goes here? )],
        'emails' => ['required', 'array'],
        'emails.*' => ['required', 'max:255', 'email', 'distinct', Rule::unique('brand_managers', 'email')->ignore( //what goes here? )],
        'contactNumbers' => ['array'],
        'contactNumbers.*' => ['numeric'],
        'groupCheckbox' => ['required', 'min:1'],
    ]);
}
```

With the unique validation rule on 'name' I can ignore the id that is coming with the `$id` using route model binding, but with the contactNames and contactEmails this needs to check a table that has a manyToMany relationship - 
how do I ignore the id's of the brand_manager rows for multiple validation checks?

I will try and edit my question for more clarity

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily create validation rules dynamically as you wish.

Here is example from my current project which requires unique field except self.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$unique_check = Rule::unique('brand_managers', 'email'); // table with some unique rows

//if you need ignore multiple rows/multiple conditions
$unique_check->where(function ($query) use ($brand) {
    return $query->whereNotIn('id', $brand->brand_managers->pluck('id')->toArray());
});

$request->validate([
    'emails.*' => [ // promocode unique string column
        'required',
        $unique_check
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer - unfortunately, I can't get this to work

Comment: This doesn't work for manyToMany relationships - this is where my issue lies

Comment: @CodeBoyCode then i don't understand what kind of uniqueness you need with manyToMany and is it even possible :)

Second example with query access also doesn't fit your need? Should be able to check whenever you want

Comment: could you help me understand your code, using my code above?

Comment: i have the $id from the brand - but I can't the ignore find the brand_manager id's linked to the $brand (using $brand->brand_managers->pluck('id) - this gives you an array of id's) but how does this work with getting those id's of the rows from a many to many relationship?

Comment: @CodeBoyCode tried to adapt example for your code, check it

Comment: thank you that works - i had to make a change to the $unique_check to $unique_check = Rule::unique('brand_managers', 'email'); - thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', Rule::unique('brands')->ignore($id)],
    'contactNames' => ['required', 'array'],
    'contactNames.*' => ['required', 'max:255', 'string', 'distinct',.$brand->id, // ID of record which want to ignore 
    'emails' => ['required', 'array'],
    'emails.*' => ['required', 'max:255', 'email', 'distinct', .$brand->id, // ID of record which want to ignore
    'contactNumbers' => ['array'],
    'contactNumbers.*' => ['numeric'],
    'groupCheckbox' => ['required', 'min:1'],
]);`
```

pass id want to ignore at time of update records.

more information check https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation